# Erro spawn UNKNOWN ao tentar criar um react-app

Tags: react-native

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar criar uma aplicação usando o comando create-react-app e não estou conseguindo resolver de forma alguma.

Aparece isso:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\JV\Desktop\React\meu-site.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\JV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\JV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\JV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
    at C:\Users\JV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting meu-site/ from C:\Users\JV\Desktop\React
Done.
```

Se alguém souber como resolver, ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score -2):

Ao invés de executar diretamente o create-react-app da [instalação global](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12022), execute ele via [npx](https://github.com/npm/npx), com o seguinte comando abaixo no seu terminal:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Então, tentei utilizando via npx, mas ele continua dando esse spawn UNKNOWN

Comment: Ao abrir o terminal / cmd, tenta abrir ele com permissão de administrador e depois executar o comando do npx novamente. 

Se não funcionar, tenta executar o comando com o https://cmder.net/

Comment: Ainda assim, não funcionou.